# Integer (literal) union type, with NaN as valid return value

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a (comparison) function with an union return type. It can return `-1`, `1` or `0`. However, I need a special case ("result") for when at least one of the items being compared is not defined. The compiler allows me to add `null` as a potential return value, but not `NaN` (which, in some scenarios would make sense, e.g. comparing numbers or dates).

This compiles

```
function myFunc(item1: MyType, item2: MyType): -1 | 0 | 1 | null {
   ...
}
```

but for this one, the compiler says it "Cannot find name NaN":

```
function myFunc(item1: MyType, item2: MyType): -1 | 0 | 1 | NaN {
   ...
}
```

Why is `NaN` not allowed? Is there a way to use `NaN`?

Comment: NaN is not an int its a float, that's probably why TS doesn't like it.

Comment: @mfeineis sure, but this `function bla(): 1 | "3" | null { ... }`also compiles.

Comment: JavaScript do not differ between int and float. Both are the same type `Number`. I think that NaN is `Number` too.

Comment: I'd wager that 1 | "3" | null is inferred as type any. Literal types is a TS feature they may have their own rules :-)

Comment: Yes, my point was that the literal type don't "need" to be of the same type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NaN` itself is not a type, instead it is a `const` value of type `Number`. So there is no way to define anything as being of the type NaN.

That makes sense, because the literal types for numbers are all single values e.g. -1, or a union of the literal values `1 | 0 | -1` but `NaN` isn't a single value as no NaN ever compares equal to any other it is effectively an infinite set of values.

I would suggest that using `NaN` to indicate a particular result from your function is a bad idea as the only way you can test for getting that result is to call another function. Better to add `null` or `undefined` to the return type (or if you don't like that how about a literal string).

Keep in mind that:

```
let foo = NaN;
switch(foo) {
    case 1: console.log('got 1'); break
    case NaN: console.log('got NaN'); break;
    default: console.log('other');
}
```

will output 'other'.

So you could just do this:

```
function myFunc(item1: MyType, item2: MyType): -1 | 0 | 1 | 'not comparable' {
   ...
}
```

and then you can just compare the result against 'not comparable'.

Comment: Set aside the scope of the function (which was more of an example, rather than the actual problem -- I ended up using `null`). The fact is, that I can consider all of the values (`-1`, `0`, `1` and `NaN`) as constants. This, in turn, means that I have a function which should be able to return one (constant) value, out of a specific set of values. The TS compiler does not agree...

Comment: yes, but my point is that NaN is not a single value, rather it is a class of values.

Comment: Being a class of values doesn't preclude it from being a type; classes are types, after all. It's just that it isn't a type; it could be, but it isn't. There's a [proposal to make it a type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682) on GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike `1`, `NaN` can not be used as a `literal type` (i.e. a type that only contain that literal value).

```
const n1 = 1, n2 = NaN;
typeof n1; // 1
typeof n2; // number
```

We could also use `number` as the return type, but this would allow more return values like `-2`. If you wanted to limit the options, `null` looks good to me.